# Появился непонятный скролл в мобильной версии

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Появился не понятный скролл в мобильной версии, справа. Все перепробовал, не могу понять как починить??? спасибо!
Вот проект: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6yBSacgA5HbbVBnZGdpdWcwa1U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти блоки у вас выпадают из родителя
[image]

Comment: спасибо! Скажите,  это вы просто бордер добавили или это какой-то отладчик?

Comment: да бордер кинул на * селектор

Comment: а, ясно. А не подскажите новичку что-то интересное для отладки, кроме хрома (инструмент разработчика)

Comment: ахах, да сам новичок) так что даже не знаю что и посоветовать)